# I need Youtube API3 + PHP Script for video uploading from website to directly into my youtube cahnnel

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

i am trying to develop web application for video upload from website to youtube channel.

I have already created Client ID, Client secret and API Key.

But i don't know how to use it, also found tutorial on online but any time i unable to complete this script.

anybody have ready-made script, so i can complete my project.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube's developers site has PHP video upload sample code [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#upload_a_video).

Comment: I have already using this code but i getting some error like Warning: Unexpected character in input: ' in /home/worldwe4/public_html/GoogleClientApi/src/file.mp4 on line 1